# Component doesn't load when called from react NavigationContainer

Tags: react-native, navigation, hamburger-menu

I am trying to create a burger nav taht navigates me to my component pages but I can't get the page to load properly when it is called. It appears to enter the pages componentDidMount() function but will not load anything else. Here is the navigation burger menu code

```
//Navigation Drawer
import {
    createDrawerNavigator,
    DrawerContentScrollView,
    DrawerItemList,
    DrawerItem,
} from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

//react and ui/ux components
import React from 'react';
import {
   //Blah blah blah
} from 'react-native';

import TodaysJobs from '../views/TodaysJobs';
import TomorrowsJobs from '../views/TomorrowsJobs';

function Feed() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Feed Screen</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function CustomDrawerContent(props) {
  return (
    <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
        <DrawerItemList {...props} />
        <DrawerItem label="Help" onPress={() => {
            console.log('Navigating to: Today\'s Jobs Original')
            props.navigation.navigate('TodaysJobs')
        }} />
    </DrawerContentScrollView>
  );
}

//create component
class Navigation extends React.Component {

    //disable navigation bar
    static navigationOptions = { headerShown: false }

    render() {
        return (
            <NavigationContainer>
                <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Feed" drawerContent={props => CustomDrawerContent(props)}>
                      <Drawer.Screen name="Feed" component={Feed} />
                      <Drawer.Screen name="TodaysJobs" component={TodaysJobs} />
                </Drawer.Navigator>
            </NavigationContainer>
        );
    }
}

export default Navigation;
```

Whenever I try to load `TodaysJobs` it goves me the loading screen and says that the component mounted via a console log but it just loads forever. None of my other console logs show either that includes `componentDidLoad`. Here is that pages code...

/

```
/loading wait spinner overlay
import Loader from '../components/Loader'

//react and ui/ux components
import React from 'react'
import {
    ...Stuff here
} from 'react-native'

//create component
class TodaysJobs extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        ...stuff here

        this.componentDidLoad = this.componentDidLoad.bind(this)
        this.componentDidUnload = this.componentDidUnload.bind(this)
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        console.log('Today\'s Jobs component mounted')  //THIS GETS CALLED
        this.props.navigation.addListener('willFocus', this.componentDidLoad)
    }

    componentDidLoad() {
        console.log('Today\'s Jobs component loaded') //THIS DOES NOT

        //FIREBASE CALLS

        this.setState({
            loading: false
        })
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <View>
                <Loader loading={this.state.loading} /> //THIS LOADER CONSTANTLY SPINS
                { !this.state.loading
                    <Mapping
                        //Mapping props
                    />
                }
            </View>
        )
    }
}

export default TodaysJobs
```

So it seems to navigate to it but just bugs out. I had it working with `<CustomButton text={"Today's Jobs"} onPress={() => { this.props.navigation.navigate('TodaysJobs') }}/>` but now I want a burger nav instead of a page of buttons so not sure what the difference is between a button and the burger nav.

Please help.
Thanks

Comment: componentDidLoad: Is that some custom hook you've made, or did you mean componentDidUpdate?

Comment: Sorry yes I accidentally removed that code. I have added it now

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out it works if I change 
`this.props.navigation.addListener('willFocus', this.componentDidLoad)`
to
`this.props.navigation.addListener('willFocus', this.componentDidLoad())`

Anyone know why I now need to call it as a function?

Thanks